# javadoc: error - java.lang.NullPointerException when creating javadoc for a class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javadoc

i have made a small program with one class only, the program is working fine with no errors or warnings, but when i try to make javadoc from it i get this error

> javadoc: error - java.lang.NullPointerException

here is the class source code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;


/** 
* This class represent each player in the game. 
* <p>
* Most of the methods and algorithms in <b>ProjectOOPDS</b> class are based on this class.
* <p>
* This class shows the hands of the players, win counts, scores and resets the values 
* for each player, in each round and each game.
*
*
*@see ProjectOOPDS
**@since 2017-09-17
*/
class Player
{ 
    public String player = "";
    public int winCount = 0;
    public String[] hand = new String[3]; 
    public int points = 0;
    public int totalPoints = 0;

    private String h = " ";

    public Player(){}
    public Player(String player){
        this.player = player;
        this.winCount = winCount;

    }
    /** show the players' hand.*/
    public String showHand(){ 
        return player + " cards: " + viewHand();
    }
    /** shows how many times the player has won.*/
    public String showWinCount(){ 
        return player + " = " + winCount;
    }
    /** used for the other players that did not win.*/
    public String showScore(){ 
        return " |  " + "Sum = " + (points%10);
    }
     /** used for the player that has won the round.*/
    public String showScoreWinner(){
        return " |  " + "Sum = " +  (points%10) + "  | " + " Winner";
    }
    /** reset for rounds.*/
    public void reset(){ 
        points = 0;
        Arrays.fill(hand, null);
        h = " ";
    }
    /** when tie in <b>ProjectOOPDS</b> class.*/
    public String tie(){ 
        return player + " Total points(non-Rightmost digit): " + totalPoints;
    }
    /** reset for game. */
    public void resetGame(){ 
        reset();
        winCount = 0;
        totalPoints = 0;
    }
    /** get the hand to show in showHand().*/
    private String viewHand(){ 
        for(String s: hand){
            h = h + (s + " ");
        }
        return h;

    }
}
```

i tried to make javadoc from the main class and it worked, but i don't know why this one isn't working.

Thank you.

Comment: Which IDE do you use to generate Javadocs? and what are the steps you did? did you include jdk lib in it?

Comment: i am using NetBeans. opened console went to the directory where my .java files are (from console) ,then wrote "javadoc -d HTML Player.java ProjectOOPDS*.java". no.                                                                                      it's just a console program.

Comment: So you *aren't* using Netbeans to generate the Javadoc. Why not?

Comment: No, sorry i didn't notice that the question raju sharma posted said that.

Comment: You haven't answered my question in any way. Nor have you provided any convincing evidence for your claim, or your answer.

Comment: Sorry i don't know what's wrong with me today.
The answer to your question is: i am using sublime and console because i am used to them, i tried to use netbeans before but i didn't know how to use it so i just ignored it and used sublime and console.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it myself, apparently when you want to make `javadoc`, your code must not have any `null` values, it will work correctly when compiled but that's not the case with `javadoc`. I had a null value in my code, so it need to be changed from this:

```
public void reset(){ 
        points = 0;
        Arrays.fill(hand, null);
        h = " ";
    }
```

to this:

```
public void reset(){ 
        points = 0;
        Arrays.fill(hand, " ");
        h = " ";
    }
```

and that's it! The error should be fixed.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, and impossible to believe that Javadoc cares about actual parameter values.

Comment: @EJP i don't know, but i did that and it worked, and wrote what i understood from the situation.

Comment: A complete stack trace would be more convincing. I've been deep inside the internals of Javadoc, for the purpose of contributing code to it, and I've never seen anything that would justify your assertion.

Comment: That's really weird i tried to make javadoc again with the null value but it executed with no errors.

Comment: I'm not in the least surprised. You got the NPE when you *executed* your code, not from Javadoc.

Comment: So, Do i delete the question or leave it ? :)

Comment: Please leave it because I am having the same problem.